# How can I get changes in remote server conveniently

Tags: git

I know how to check the changes in local:
Get changes **before commit**:

```
git diff master
```

Get changes **after commit** && **before push**:

```
git diff origin/master
or
git diff remotes/origin/master
```

---

What I want is:

1. git clone the latest version from remote server, for example, the local version is **v1**
2. Change the remote server from the aother side, for example, the remote version is **v2**, (**local version is still v1**)
3. get the different from remote server

And, I know how to get changes in remote server by the following steps:

```
git remote foo git@github.com:user/foo.git
git fetch foo
git diff master foo/master
```

However, I want to alias one command to check the changes in remote server, for example:

```
git rdiff master
or something else
```

is that possible to get changes in remote server by one comment? Thanks.

---

By the way, I found that, there are an **origin** has been **fetched** in local repo, how can I use it without fetch it again?

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:Marslo/VimConfig.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Marslo/VimConfig.git (push)
```

Comment: Rolled back to a revision that's just the question. To provide the answer to your own question simply _create an answer_ and then, if appropriate, accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is a logical problem with this:

```
git rdiff master
```

Which remote are you going to compare against? So in the very list, it should be something like:

```
git rdiff remote_name branch_name
```

which should expand to:

```
git fetch remote_name && git diff remote_name/branch_name
```

You can create exactly that alias (in ~/.gitconfig for example):

```
[alias]
    rdiff = "!sh -c 'git fetch \"$0\" && git diff \"$0\"/\"$1\"'"
```

which tells shell to run the above command with the given parameters.

---

Some other notes:

- Instead of `git diff master`, you can simply write `git diff` which takes the diff with the current branch you are on which is not necessarily `master`.
- Instead of `git diff master foo/master`, you can simply write (if there are no local changes) `git diff foo/master` which does the same. It's easier to type since you don't repeat master twice.
- You don't need to change your remotes every time. You can have multiple remotes in the same repository. Therefore, you can do (note that you missed `add`):

  ```
  git remote add foo git@github.com:user/foo.git
  ```

  and keep it there in your repository forever. Now you can still interact with `origin`, which is the remote automatically created when you cloned your repository. At the same time, you can also interact with the other remote you created, named `foo`. So in the same repository, you could do:

  ```
  # get updates from origin
  git fetch origin
  git merge origin/master

  # check them against foo
  git rdiff foo master
  ```

Comment: Hi @Shahbaz, thanks! It works!! I changed it as `rdiff = "!bash -c 'git fetch && git diff master remotes/origin/master'"`

Comment: And, I made rlog, :), `rlog = "!bash -c 'git fetch && git plog remotes/origin/master'"`, the plog (pretty log) is alias as `plog = log --max-count=3 --color --graph\n --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr)  %C(blue)<%an>%Creset'\n --abbrev-commit --date=relative`

Comment: @MarsloJiao, as you want! There's a lot you can do. Once you get more advanced though, you might want to turn it back to using arguments instead of always working with origin and master since you could be working with many remotes and branches.

Comment: The master branch used quite frequently. So, I alias it only for master.

Comment: Hey @Shahbaz, you can see my screenshot about it, :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Shahbaz.

**rdiff** used to get the different between local repo and remote server, the alias is:

```
rdiff = "!bash -c 'git fetch && git diff master remotes/origin/master'"
```

It will looks like
[image: rdiff]

And, I made "**rlog**" and "**rlogs**" as well, it to get the log from remote server:

```
plog = log --max-count=3 --color --graph\n --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C( blue)<%an>%Creset'\n --abbrev-commit --date=relative
plogs = log --color --graph\n --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(blue)<%an>%Cr eset'\n --abbrev-commit --date=relative
rlog = "!bash -c 'git fetch && git plog remotes/origin/master'"
rlogs = "!bash -c 'git fetch && git plogs remotes/origin/master'"
```

It will show:
[image: rlogs]